# search for location using maps api android sdk

Tags: android, search, google-maps

I am lacking the knowledge of how to search for a location using an `EditText` and `button` when the person enters the longitude and latitude or even just an address into the `EditText` section an pushes the `Button` I want the map to go to that location. If anyone has any info on how to do so or even a tutorial it would be much appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String uri = "geo:"+ latitude + "," + longitude;

startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

or with an adress:

```
geo:latitude,longitude
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=business+near+city
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

For instance:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:38.899533,-77.036476");
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.Action_VIEW,uri);
startActivity(it);
```

For navigation:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + location)); 
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: The code keeps popping up on the map saying that it is `unable to load the URL`. is the permissions or certain code that I should have in order for this to work properly?

Comment: Try the example (post edited)  
You will easily understand how you will have to format lat and lon ;-)

Comment: I am working on it right now, but can you put up the other one again to. The one that took you to the navigation on that map. I am actually going to need that one next

Comment: Just added navigation intent, is that enough for you to?